# Android Fragment behaving weird

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment, android-3.0-honeycomb

The activity_main.xml is like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button_one_activity_one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="First Button"
    />

<fragment
android:name="fragments.FirstFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/first_fragment" />    

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/button_two_activity_one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Second Button"
    />        
</LinearLayout>
```

The main activity class is like this

```
package com.example.testfragmentshoneycomb;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

first_fragment.xml is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/grey" >"

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_one_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text View one" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_two_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text View two" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_three_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text View three" />

</LinearLayout>
```

FirstFragment class is like this

```
package fragments;


import com.example.testfragmentshoneycomb.R;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);
    return view;
}

}
```

It shows only first button and nothing else on the screen. If I remove the first button from activity_main.xml it shows the fragment but doesn't show the second button.

Min SDK version is 11 and build target is android 4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set `android:orientation="vertical"` in your activity layout.

Answer (score 3):

Its because by default LinearLayout's orientation is `horizontal`. Therefore the whole screens width is captured by the `First Button` and `Fragment`.

Are you sure you want to see it like?

```
First_Button              Fragment            Second_Button
```

If Yes the use `layout_weight`. If No then give `orientation=vertical` to LinearLayout which will show your layout output as

```
First_Button              
Fragment
Second_Button
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know about the default behavior

Answer (score 1):

set LinearLayout orientation to vertical, it's horizontal by default.
read docs carefully

Answer (score 1):

Use the following layout :

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button_one_activity_one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="First Button"
    />

<fragment
android:name="fragments.FirstFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/first_fragment" />    

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/button_two_activity_one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Second Button"
    />        
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: kindly explain the problem that OP is having.

Comment: by default linearlayout takes  orientation has Horizontal. In Button View you have set android:layout_width="match_parent" which means it will fill the entire width pushing the fragment & 2nd Button   . so fragment & 2nd Button is not visible .

Comment: whoops!! that need to be added to your answer not comment :)